# Significance of Symbol from Asura's Wrath

Tags: symbolism, meaning

[image: Chakravartin]

In the above image, at the mid-bottom section of the screen, is shown a symbol, of whose origin i do not know, appearing within the final fight between Asura and Chakravartin in the game: Asura's Wrath. According to Wikipedia, ["Asura's Wrath takes elements from Hindu and Buddhist mythologies"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asura%27s_Wrath) thus I have posted here, inferring that it is hinduistic in origin, questioning what the significance of this symbol is and it's meaning. 
[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kV46V2uniqs&t=18831s) is a link to a cut-scene compilation of Asura's Wrath, timestamped to the scene portrayed in the image above if so needed.